# How I can send the link through SMS gateway using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, sms-gateway

I intergraded the SMS gateway in my Laravel project I want to sms to the client registration link through SMS but I tried the same way it's going but can't click. And mainly I plan to take the client's WhatsApp number but In WhatsApp message is coming but can't click.

Please help me fix this issue.

```
$smsMsg = notifications::where('sms_subject','Student Register Link')->first();

        if($request->stud_nic!="")
        {
            $student = students::where('st_nic', $request->stud_nic)->first();

            $studName = $student->st_fname;
            $phone = $student->st_phone;
            $studNic = $request->stud_nic;

            $nic = Hash::make($studNic[0]);
            $link = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/StudentCount/".$nic;
            $addName = str_replace("{{name}}",$studName,$smsMsg->message);
            $addNic = str_replace("{{link}}",$link,$addName);
            $newMsg = urlencode($addNic);

            $api = "https://sms-gateway-api.php?key=".$key."&acc=".$acc."&type=".$type."&phone=".$phone."&text=".$newMsg;
            $response = file_get_contents($api);
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried sending a link that's to a top-level domain, rather than 127.0.0.1?  It's possible there's some filtering in the app itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Links, phone numbers, etc are usually detected by your messaging application (they parse the text, and if it feels its a link/phone number, it makes them clickable), and text messages are usually just plaintext. There is no standard way to format them.

So most likely your SMS application is not detecting it. Try sending it to some other device, maybe it might detect the link. But there's no guarantee it will work on every SMS application

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue and I fixed it. The issue was I used the IP address that will disable the link when using the IP. After I changed into the domain it's working.

```
$smsMsg = notifications::where('sms_subject','Student Register Link')->first();
    
            if($request->stud_nic!="")
            {
                $student = students::where('st_nic', $request->stud_nic)->first();
    
                $studName = $student->st_fname;
                $phone = $student->st_phone;
                $studNic = $request->stud_nic;
    
                $nic = Hash::make($studNic[0]);
                $link = "http://testing.com/StudentCount/".$nic;
                $addName = str_replace("{{name}}",$studName,$smsMsg->message);
                $addNic = str_replace("{{link}}",$link,$addName);
                $newMsg = urlencode($addNic);
    
                $api = "https://sms-gateway-api.php?key=".$key."&acc=".$acc."&type=".$type."&phone=".$phone."&text=".$newMsg;
                $response = file_get_contents($api);
            }
```